# maintaining code structure and locking the admin folder

Tags: coldfusion, railo, lucee

I am trying to use the following to make a page security enable for the admin folders of my website

the structure of my application is like the switch case statements

`index.cfm` page has the `switch.cfm` which further defines the code as:

```
<cfswitch expression="#mode#">
<cfcase value="admin.1"><cfinclude template="1.cfm"></cfcase>
<cfdefaultcase><cfinclude template="login.cfm"></cfcase>
</cfswitch>
```

now in my `application.cfc` i have defined like this

```
<cfif (NOT structKeyExists( session, "isLoggedIn" )) OR (session.isLoggedIn eq false) AND CGI.query_string contains 'admin'>
<cfinclude template="index.cfm"> - why `index`, it will include the `switch.cfm` and `switch.cfm` has the `defaultcase` of `login.cfm`, so apparently it will include `login.cfm` - **This is why i think it should do**.
```

now when i call my page as:

`http://localhost/?mode=admin.1` - it goes into it, rather than sending the user to the `login.cfm`, am i missing something

Answer (score 1):

I believe your logic is wrong...

You're saying:

if not logged in, include index.cfm

In index.cfm you are asking,

if mode == admin.1 then include 1
else include the login

You are passing in the correct mode, so admin.1 is run.

You probably want something like:

```
<cfif (NOT structKeyExists( session, "isLoggedIn" )) OR (session.isLoggedIn eq false) AND CGI.query_string contains 'admin'>
    <cfinclude template="login.cfm">
<cfelse>
    <!--- this should mean the user is logged in --->
    <cfinclude template="index.cfm">
</cfif>
```

Or something like that...

Comment: cannot include alone login as i said above like this:  - need to call the `index`, it will include the `switch.cfm` and `switch.cfm` has the `defaultcase case` of `login.cfm`, so apparently it will include `login.cfm` - **This is why i think it should do**.

Comment: Then in the index file you will need to do a check to see if you are logged in...  index is being called because you aren't logged in, then in index you are looking for a URL variable, if it exists show otherwise show the login... If you are logged in, index will not be called, unless that's in code not shown.

Comment: I still feel you should probably have the if not logged in include login.cfm in the Application.cfc file... Then if you are are logged in, it will pass through to the index file which contains the correct switch

Comment: i am getting confused now by your explanation, can you be more detailed and do i need to add only logic only in single file or multiple files.

Comment: It can be done many ways.  The problem you currently have is that your application.cfc file includes the index file when you are not logged in.  This index file works out what to include, no matter if you are logged in or not.

Comment: The quickest fix, would be to do the login check above the cfswitch statement and move the cfswitch into the else section of the login check.  So: if (not logged in) {include login.cfm} else { cfswitch statement }